# window.scrollTo(0, 0) and scrollTop = 0 not working on Angular 2 route changes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is an extremely frustrating issue. I'm done with my application other then this one last thing. I've been listening for changes on the router, and trying to have it autoscroll to the top upon that change. I've literally tried 10 different solutions on Google and nothing has any effect. I know it's related to the router, but I can't figure out why exactly it won't scroll. Here is the code I'm currently using.

app.component.ts

```html
this.router.events.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(event => {
  window.scroll(0, 0);
});
```

app.component.html

```html
<div class="mainbody bgc-white">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I've tried several variations of this, specifically grabbing the router-outlet element with ElementRef and setting scrollTop = 0, but that had no effect either. Also tried using document.body and that had no effect. What am I missing here?

Comment: Take a look at the last answers [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7791)

Comment: I've tried everything on there. Even when I build the autoscroll service, the scroll never actually works. For whatever reason, on every solution, my scroll does nothing.

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and quite pointless, because it's usually solved by calling window.scroll on route events, and it is expected to work.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. It isn't solved by doing that in every case which is why I posted it.

Comment: If you are using angular material, I got my peace with this answer: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11552

Answer (score 6):

I've just managed to fix the same problem with a setTimeout hack like so:

```
scrollToTop(): void {
  setTimeout(() => window.scroll(0, 0), 0);
}
```

Comment: Angular is so bad.. god why do u have to do hacks like this

Answer (score 3):

Finally was able to get this working. Nothing else was working for me.

I had to create this scroll service: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/src/app/shared/scroll.service.ts

Then inject it into each individual page that I wanted to autoscroll to the top, then call it in the page like so.

```html
ngAfterViewInit() {
  [your scroll service].scrollToTop();
}
```

Also had to put this id (this is what the service uses) on the div around my router-outlet, as opposed to the body. When I was targeting the body tag, the scroll was doing nothing. When I targeted the div right outside the router-outlet, it worked.

```html
<div id="top-of-page">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I got this solution from the page linked by BogdanC, but had to modify it to work in my situation.

Comment: `imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'top', preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],` "scrollPositionRestoration" will take care of it on routing.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your app.component is using router-outlet

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.routerSubscription = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    )
      .subscribe(() => {
        document.querySelector('mat-drawer-content').scrollTop = 0;
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.routerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: You may also want to try: ```document.querySelector('mat-sidenav-content').scrollTop = 1500;``` as described here: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11552#issuecomment-392708519 depending on what kind of angular material component you are wrapping your ui

Answer (score 1):

Yes I am using Angular 5 and the same code which you have used did not work, so I have used the below code which works well either,

```
this.router.events.subscribe(evt => {
    if (evt instanceof NavigationEnd) {
         document.body.scrollTop = 0; // scroll top to body element
    }
});
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me when the site is visited on a mobile Phone. Thanks.